# dispatch in Redux won't add new data in store

Tags: reactjs, redux, dispatch, toolkit

I have an array of incomes that I display in a table. There's a "+" button to add a new income. I want to increment database and redux store with a dispatch.

Increment database works fine, but I have to reload page to see new data.

Why my dispatch does not update the `state.data` of incomes ?

```
// AddNewData.tsx
[...]
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FieldValues> = async (data) => {
        if (user) {
            const formData = {
                userId: user._id,
                label: data.label,
                amount: data.amountInput,
            };

            dispatch(addUserIncome(formData));
        }
    };
[...]
```

```
//incomes_slice.ts

import { IDataState, IEntry } from "../../helpers/Interfaces";
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { deleteData, getData, updateData, addData } from "../../APIs/UserData";
import { Notifier } from "../../helpers/Notifier";

const initialState: IDataState = {
    data: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null,
};

export const getUserIncomes = createAsyncThunk("incomes/getUserIncomes", (userId: string) => {
    return getData("incomes", userId);
});

export const addUserIncome = createAsyncThunk("incomes/addUserIncome", async (data: { userId: string; label: string; amount: number }) => {
    const response = await addData("incomes", data).then((res) => {
        const newEntry: IEntry = {
            _id: res.data.income._id,
            user: data.userId,
            label: data.label,
            amount: data.amount,
        };

        return newEntry;
    });

    return response;
});

export const updateUserIncome = createAsyncThunk("incomes/updateUserIncome", async (data: { id: string; data: IEntry }) => {
    await updateData("incomes", data.id, data.data);
    return data;
});

export const deleteUserIncome = createAsyncThunk("incomes/deleteUserIncome", async (incomeId: string) => {
    await deleteData("incomes", incomeId);
    return incomeId;
});

const incomesSlice = createSlice({
    name: "incomes",
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(getUserIncomes.pending, (state) => {
            state.loading = true;
        });
        builder.addCase(getUserIncomes.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.data = action.payload;
            state.error = null;
        });
        builder.addCase(getUserIncomes.rejected, (state, action) => {
            state.loading = false;
            state.error = action.error.message;
            action.error.message && Notifier(action.error.message, "error");
        });
        builder.addCase(addUserIncome.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.data.push(action.payload);
        });
        builder.addCase(updateUserIncome.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.data = state.data.map((income) => {
                if (income._id === action.payload.id) {
                    return action.payload.data;
                }
                return income;
            });
        });
        builder.addCase(deleteUserIncome.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            state.data = state.data.filter((income) => income._id !== action.payload);
        });
    },
});

export const incomesReducer = incomesSlice.reducer;
```

PS: `addData` function is just an axios.post that works fine.

Comment: How do you get the data out of the store? What makes you determine that it did not change?

Comment: I use useAppSelector to retrieve data when page load. And when I create new income, the redux store is not incremented. That’s why I know the redux state did not change

Comment: Maybe share that code as well (and not only that one line, but also how you work with that data afterwards), I've seen at least a dozen questions where people used that wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `addUserIncome` you are mixing styles of awaiting a promise.

**Instead of this:**

```
const response = await addData("incomes", data).then((res) => {
  const newEntry: IEntry = {
    _id: res.data.income._id,
    user: data.userId,
    label: data.label,
    amount: data.amount,
  };

  return newEntry;
});
```

**Either use this:**

```
try {
  const response = await addData("incomes", data);
  // do stuff
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

**Or do this:**

```
addData("incomes", data).then((res) => {
  // do stuff
})
```

Comment: Sorry, I shared only the specific code. I have a createSlice function. Sorry for the misunderstanding

Comment: No problem - can you share more of your code, like where is the `initialState` defined? What does your normal `reducer` look like?

Comment: I updated the post with the full slice. Hope that it helps point my error

Comment: Please also show the code for `addUserIncome` --- I assume it's not missing from your code?

Comment: You can now find the `addUserIcome` in the slice

Comment: I added the try and catch, made me see that I didnt add the `response.data._id` in the response in my API... sorry for the time. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave a comment (just don't have enough credit yet).
You said you checked your store? Are you sure that the data is changed in the store?
(Because this is async of course, and you're not managing loading and pending state of your call, probably your UI is rendered before the data is updated.)

Comment: Yes I have checked my store. Actualy I have the same logic for incomes, and for expenses. One works fine, the other one with same slices logic dont. Can't understand why